# Delete comments by default after 1 month

Tags: discussion, comments

Stack Overflow has always been very insistent that comments are ephemeral. However, that insistence clashes with our daily experience of answers that have been enriched and improved by comments. The comments certainly feel permanent enough for some of to spend time in crafting them just so and making them really useful.

And yet, the comments also serve another function - that of a discussion board. Requests for improvements and long-drawn battles about details are not uncommon. That part of commenting is not really Q&A. The *results* of discussion belong in the question or in the answer. The discussion itself is not relevant.

To resolve this duality of use for comments, I propose the following changes:

- All comments not specially marked are deleted after 1 month (or another suitable fixed time period).
- A comment on a question can be marked for preservation by the questioner.
- A comment on an answer can be marked for preservation by the answerer.
- High-rep users and gold badge users can mark comments for preservation as well.
- Highly-upvoted comments ARE NOT PROTECTED from deletion
- Comments on Meta comments are treated as before, no automatic delete.
- Existing comments are grandfathered in. Some cleanup effort will need to be considered in the future.

This should give everybody enough incentive to edit good comments into the answers and the questions, and to ignore (or not write) bad comments.

Flagging still works as before. A user who marks too many flagged/deleted comments for preservation may lose the marking privilege.

Comment: ["Comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140703/let-comments-decay-by-default-add-option-to-make-them-permanent) [are](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182295/automatically-hide-old-comments) [ephemeral"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310199/automatic-comment-deletion-based-on-time-on-the-main-sites)

Comment: I don't see this as a problem that needs to be solved. If there's a fight going on or if the comments just aren't relevant anymore they can be flagged for deletion. If valuable information is in a comment instead of the post, edit the post. It otherwise isn't hurting anything to otherwise have old comments hanging around.

Comment: While reading this I got the idea that maybe we should just automatically delete any comments that receive no upvotes in a timeframe (Say, 1 month) - with no upvotes you could assume that comment is not really very useful. It wouldn't be a radical difference, but would clear out a little bit of clutter across the sites. There are probably downsides I'm not considering, so this isn't really a feature request or anything, but just an idea.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Stack Overflow has always been very insistent that comments are ephemeral.

This is technically true, but so very often misunderstood, and used to justify changes that radically clash with the actual goal of comments (that statement is attempting to describe).

Comments being ephemeral doesn't mean, *"Can be deleted at any time for any reason, because they're not actually valuable."* It doesn't even mean, *"Will never, or rarely, need to be around for a long time."* It's referring to the fact that the *goal* of a comment is to affect a change in the post it is commenting on. Many comments fail to actually achieve that goal, for numerous different reasons. It's only appropriate to delete comments *after they have successfully achieve that goal* (or for being inappropriate from the start, but that's not what this is about). Just because there is a planned obsolescence doesn't mean everything always goes to plan.

The purpose of comments is to point out some way in which they post they are commenting on could be improved. Often this means pointing out some problem in the post that needs to be addressed. However, *quite* often the author of the post either disagrees with the assessment that there's a problem, disagrees with the proposed resolution, doesn't understand the described problem, doesn't understand how to resolve it, isn't willing to take the time to edit the post to properly address it, or for some other reason, ends up not improving the post to address the problems described in the comment. In any of those cases the comment is not in fact obsolete, and therefore cannot be deleted. Deleting the comment would be removing useful information; in many cases *essential* information describing serious problems with a post.

Your solutions for keeping around comments simply don't adequately address the reasons that they're necessary in the first place. Out of all of the reasons I listed for why a post author wouldn't fix the post, almost all of them are reasons that the post author *also wouldn't mark the post as needing to stay around*. About the only time they would is if they agreed with the assessment of the problem and just didn't know how to fix it. In just about every other situation the post author either wouldn't want to keep the comment around, or would have already fixed their post. The fact that the post author doesn't understand, agree with, or want to take the time to fix, the problems pointed out in a comment, isn't a reason to delete that comment.

As for gold badge users, there just aren't enough of them to mark all of the useful comments. This is particularly true in more niche tags, that often just don't have enough activity to get even their top users gold badges in the tags.

Comment: My first hope was that, even if the answerer does not agree with a comment, they would protect it to preserve an alternative POV. Maybe too idealistic. My second hope was that the lack of comment survival would encourage the commenter to reframe the important comments as an alternative answer. Overall, I hoped that the knowledge that the comments are TRULY ephemeral will change behavior patterns for everybody.

Comment: @Arkadiy No, *very* few people would keep around such comments.  As it is they're constantly flagging comments politely telling people what's wrong with their posts as abusive and rude.  Clearly that isn't going to help.  Answers are for answers to the question, not for commentary on other posts.  Descriptions of why a given answers is problematic is not to be posted as an answer, and would merit deletion if posted as an answer.  Such content *belongs* as a comment on the answer it is commentating on.  (Until such time as the answer is edited to fix the problem it describes.)

Comment: Well, again, maybe I give too much credit to posters here, but clearly problematic answers ought to be deleted by the answerers when it becomes clear that the answer is flawed. If that is not so, the crystallized outcome of comments is a downvote or a few, and that stays.

Comment: And if the commenter has a more correct answer, it should be posted as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @Arkadiy: Why are you talking about answers now?

Comment: @Arkadiy You'd like to think so, but it *very* often doesn't happen.  I've listed numerous reasons as to why it doesn't (the reasons that they don't fix the post are almost all the same as the reasons for why they don't delete a post).  Deleting all comments explaining why an answer is problematic and leaving *only* the votes simply isn't good enough.  Too many people love upvoting any downvoted answer they see because they want to "be nice", or because "downvoting an answer without explaining why is wrong", or other rationalizations.  Having explanations of why a post is bad is *useful*.

Comment: Many times there *will* be other answers posted that don't have the problems that a given answer has.  That doesn't mean we should delete all of the comments explaining why the one answer is problematic (this leading readers to use the other, better, answer).  Sure, someone posting a different solution shouldn't do so as a comment.  But that's not what most comments are.  Additionally, just because someone knows why a given answer is problematic, or doesn't answer the question, doesn't mean that they know what the *correct* answer is.

Answer (score 19):

Counter-FR: Stop calling comments *"ephemeral"* They're more valuable than SE staff seems to want to admit.

No, don't automatically delete them. And don't waste time implementing a "marking" system for comments that would probably require yet another review queue.

> - *All comments not specially marked are deleted after 1 month (or another suitable fixed time period).*
> - *Highly-upvoted comments ARE NOT PROTECTED from deletion
>     Comments on Meta comments are treated as before, no automatic delete.*

How would this deal with existing comments? A month after implementing this, suddenly, *all* valuable comments on old answers are gone.

> - *A comment on a question can be marked for preservation by the questioner.*
> - *A comment on an answer can be marked for preservation by the answerer.*
> - *High-rep users and gold badge users can mark comments for preservation as well.*

Who will moderate these? What's to stop anyone from marking "useless" funny comments?

> - *Existing comments are grandfathered in. Some cleanup effort will need to be considered in the future.*

We don't have enough review queues yet. Let's add one for *all* the comments we currently have on SO.

---

Imagine the loss of context that this widespread deletion of comments would cause. For what purpose? What's the benefit here? I sure don't see it.

Comment: "Comments are ephemeral" is a long-standing meme at this point. It will not die.

Comment: All memes die... Eventually.

Comment: Added a note on existing comments. Moderating is still done by flagging. From the Q: " A user who marks too many flagged/deleted comments for preservation may automatically lose the marking privilege"

Comment: ^ Take that comment for example. If I don't mark it helpful, it will disappear, and your response to my answer would be gone. If someone _does_ mark it as useful, and I disagree, I'm stuck with a "useless" comment on my answer. I don't see the advantage of a system like this. What's wrong with just flagging the bad apples as _"No longer needed"_?

Comment: That comment is a perfecty example indeed. It contains 2 parts: one informs you that I updated the question, one refers you to an already existing part of the question. All the information in that comment is already elsewhere.