# Put a self-delete timer on some comments?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments

In a [recent meta Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390442/all-my-comments-with-a-certain-tag-are-getting-deleted) @TylerH noted that comments are "transient" and "second-class citizens", and that is often true, but not always.  For example, there are many comments along the lines of "thanks" or "please accept my answer" and clearly those are useful for a day or two at most.

Conversely, some comments are clearly not transient in nature nor should they be considered second-class.  The obvious example is when answers are disguised as comments, and sometimes have significant upvotes, but there are also lots of in-between comments that clearly have long term usefulness, yet are more appropriate as comments.  These in-between comments get some protection in that you need 3 flags or a moderator to delete them, but the lack of visibility into this process by anyone except a moderator nonetheless makes it very opaque in the event that something useful is deleted.

**Feature request:  Allow both users and moderators to put a self-delete timer on comments.**  For example, the classic "Please accept my answer if it helped you" can be nice reminder to a new user, but clearly should not exist for more than a day or two.  This could perhaps be setup so that lower rep users default to comments that self-delete after 24 hours, but higher rep users defualt to permanent comments.

As a corrollary to this, perhaps this might also allow the more permanent-type comments to have better transparency in the case of deletion.  Again, it might be connected to user rep level.

Benefits:

- Provide moderators a middle ground for dealing with flagged comments.  We can perhaps agree that the usefulness of many comments is genuinely debatable -- especially to a moderator without specific tag knowledge.  With an immediate deletion, no one can possibly benefit from the comment.  But with a delayed deletion via timer, it ensures that the comment generates no long term clutter, yet many more users get a chance to see the comment, in the event it is useful.
- General reduction of clutter for cases where someone intends to come back and delete a comment but forgets.

Comment: I often find myself wishing for something like this myself. Too bad that it'll never be implemented.

Comment: I think this'd be awesome to have. But when I think about the dev time they'd have to spend to make it work and all the other awesome features we desperately *need*...well, I think just staying on top of your own comments is good enough. (especially since most ppl only comment a couple times a day)

Comment: with the Stack API and some userscript this is buildable by the community

Comment: I would swear that this has been suggested before, but I can't find the post right now, either here or on MSE. I did find [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/371961), which is similar, but more blunt. Your opt-in approach is definitely better. But, I still don't think it is worth the effort. First, there's the fact that "transient"/"ephemeral" labels getting tossed on comments is a tired meme, and not fully accurate. Second, there's no way to know that a comment *will* become "no longer needed". Obsolescence requires action by a third-party. Flagging these still makes the most sense.

Comment: Ah, [here's another related suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320552/) that replaces the timer with a "read receipt". I'm still not compelled by the idea of automating this. I'd rather just have moderators stick to deleting comments that are *obviously* obsolete and/or useless, and leaving edge cases alone. That is, in fact, precisely what I do. If there's any chance that the information in the comment might add value, and there's nothing in it that is doing harm, I'll leave it alone.

Comment: Good old "call someone @#$@ and let it disappear before flagged" request... I do want this feature (or delete by recipient variant) ... as long as you have suggestion to solve name calling problem.

Comment: @CodyGray I was thinking "Thank you" comments that aren't needed in the long run but are nice in the moment.

Comment: @JL2210 Eh...we've got folks who runs bots that will automatically flag such comments within minutes of posting, so there's no guarantee that anyone will even see them. When I first became a moderator, that gave me pause, because I was thinking the same as you: I shouldn't delete these until the person they're aimed at can actually see them. But then I came around to just deleting them on sight because they serve no real purpose. On Stack Overflow, "thank you" is spelled with a big orange upward-facing triangle.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov it'll still show up for mods irrespective of whether it has been deleted or not so you'd just flag the OP and mention it in a custom flag. Arguably, if someone really wanted to name call, they'd do it and they'd delete it there and then rather than wait for a timer.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the feedback on this.  I have to admit that it seems like less of a good idea to me today compared to yesterday.  I guess really the issue is that the whole setup of comments is less than ideal and maybe this would help but it would probably be a band-aid at best.  Gosh tho, I really do think the comment system here could and should be improved.